# Tradingview Pinescript Strategy Exit on EMA cross

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I created a strategy, entries work, SL, TP work. All is fine, but I wanted to also add Exit on EMA cross.

For some reason it does not work. Maybe someone can help?

I have added inputs for ema's I have plotted the ema's - they are visible, all works fine so far,

so I have added this to have one more exit condition and this does nothing:

```
closelong =  ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
closeshort =  ta.crossunder(ema1, ema2)

if closelong
    strategy.close("Close long",  alert_message = message_closelong)
if closeshort
    strategy.close("Close short", alert_message = message_closeshort)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Close long" and "Close short" must match the strategy entry, which was buy and sell

Answer (score 0):

How do you launch the long and short entry?

```
strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, alert_message, disable_alert) → void
```

Note that the ID must match when you invoke the `strategy.close(""...)`:

```
if long_condition
    strategy.entry("Long",...)

if close_condition
    strategy.close("Long",...)
```

Comment: As it is written, your answer is a bit unclear.  You start off with a question, and I'm not sure if you mean it rhetorically or not since that wasn't part of the original question.  If this is an answer, I'd recommend rephrasing it as a statement, rather than a rhetorical question.